# Ember.Js Using TransitionTo Route with dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember application (version 3.14) which I'd like to do a transition to a Route with dynamic segment

I'd like to redirect to /projects/other/2020 when user visits /projects/other
I change my projects/other route so it looks like this but it throws me an error

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    
    model: function(){
    
    },
    redirect() {
        let year_data = {
            year: '2020'
        };
        this.transitionTo('projects.other',year_data);
    }
});
```

and this is how my projects route looks like in routes.js

```
this.route('projects', function() {
  this.route('notable',{path: '/'});
  this.route('other', function() {
    this.route('list', {path: '/:year'});
  });
});
```

these are the errors from google chrome console box

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Vog.png)

Comment: my mistake, i was trying to do a transition to /projects/other/2020 which the route is projects.other.list
changing the code to `this.transitionTo('projects.other.list',year_data)` fixes this. again this is just me being careless for not re-checking the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is pretty clear. You are trying to redirect to `projects.other.index` route which does not have any dynamic segments. Also, according to [docs](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.15/classes/Route/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo), you need to pass an id and not an object. When you pass an object, ember treats it like ready to use model. So, your code should be

```
this.transitionTo('projects.other.list', '2020');
```

Comment: passing an object also works, note that the attribute must has a same name as the dynamic segment (:year in this case). thank you for your answer. I was careless to leave out the .list.